# NoReverseMatch: Unable to pass parameter from template to view.

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to create a simple search form in Django. Here is what I have so far:

form:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_pub' pub_name=pub_name %}" method="get">
    Publication name: <input type="text" id="pub_name" name="pub_name" value="herald">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search'),
url(r'^results/(?P<pub_name>[\w]+)/$', views.search_pub, name='search_pub'),
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    return render(request, 'urlapp/search.html')

def search_pub(request, pub_name):
    pubs = Publication.objects.all().filter(title__icontains=pub_name)
    return render(request, 'app/results.html', {
        'publications': pubs
    })
```

models.py

```
class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

I get the following error when I open the search page at http://localhost:8000/search/:

```
NoReverseMatch at /search/
Reverse for 'search_pub' with keyword arguments '{'pub_name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['results/(?P<pub_name>[\\w]+)/$']
```

I verified that the regex is valid using the site [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5Eresults%2F(%3FP%3Cpub_name%3E%5B%5Cw%5D%2B)%2F%24&test_string=results%2Fherald%2F&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

If I go to the URL: http://localhost:8000/results/herald, I get the correct results.

What am I missing?

Comment: Value of `pub_name` in template seems empty?

Comment: Yes, I am not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use GET variables as if they are URL arguments. Besides, `{% url ...` values are computed on the server side, therefore you can't modify them dynamically in an HTML form. I would do the following:

First, change the following line

```
url(r'^results/(?P<pub_name>[\w]+)/$', views.search_pub, name='search_pub'),
```

to

```
url(r'^results/$', views.search_pub, name='search_pub'),
```

Then, change your view code to look like this:

```
def search_pub(request):                    # Remove pub_name from method signature
    pub_name = request.GET.get('pub_name')  # ...and fetch it from GET dict instead
    ...
```

Finally, change your `form` tag:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_pub' %}" method="get">
```

Note that from now on your URLs will be in the following form:

```
http://localhost:8000/results?pub_name=herald
```

**Update:**

If you really want to have the value in URL, you can redirect from one to the other:

Keep both URLs in your `urls.py` with *different* names:

```
url(r'^results/(?P<pub_name>[\w]+)/$', views.search_pub, name='search_pub_clean'),
url(r'^results/$', views.search_pub, name='search_pub'),
```

and the view code:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
def search_pub(request, pub_name=None):
    if pub_name is None:
        return redirect('search_pub_clean', pub_name=request.GET.get('pub_name'))
    ...
```

Comment: That's the querystring way, which I have tried already.  But I am looking to have a clean URL like `/results/pubname/year`. Should I have a separate model and form only for the search page to accomplish this?

Comment: You don't need to. You can have two URL configurations and redirect from one to the other. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is much better. I will now have a redirect to deal with. :)

Comment: This is the best method to have clean URLs. You can also implement this on the client side, using Javascript but it needs more testing and is more prone to errors.

Comment: I agree this is a really easy way without having to go for a separate server side form and model for the search form. Thanks for introducing this to me. Cheers.